# wso2esb enrich mediator deletes node soap:Header

Tags: soap, wso2-esb

I have 2 child wsse:Security in soap:Header and trying to delete one. I tried to do this with Enrich Mediator, but instead of replace soap:Header it deletes. Here is simple example that reproduces it:

```
<inSequence>
     <enrich>
        <source type="inline" clone="true">
           <soapenv:Header xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
              <foo/>
           </soapenv:Header>
        </source>
        <target xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                xpath="//soapenv:Header"/>
     </enrich>
     <log level="full"/>
  </inSequence>
```

Log mediator logs message without Header. If I add to target action="child", everything work just as expected. So i have 2 questions:
1. Why enrich mediator act like that?
2. How can i change header with other way?

Answer (score 0):

You should use **header** mediator to change SOAP Headers

Have a look there : https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Header+Mediator

Sample to add a custom header :

```
<header xmlns:myns="http://com/header" name="myns:MyHeader" value="0"/>
```

Sample to remove it :

```
<header xmlns:myns="http://com/header" name="myns:MyHeader" action="remove"/>
```

You can use this mediator to change http headers : just add a scope attribute with a value equals to 'transport'

Comment: <header ... name="wsse:Security" action="remove"/> deletes both wsse:Security

Comment: Althought, I can save needed part in property... Thanks, it could work. But i still don't get why enrich mediator act like that.